# How much sense does a p-value of <2e-16 make?

Tags: r, regression, p-value

I ran a linear regression with one dependent and one explanatory variable. The data covers log returns of an index and log returns of a stock (natural logarithm). 
log return of stock = Alpha + Beta + log return of index + error

The p value for the Beta estimate is <2e-16. I googled the meaning of this number, which means that the p value is extremely close to zero, but it does not equal to zero.

Now I am confused, since values below 0.01 show significant results, but what if the p value is practically zero? Does it mean that the regression provides a perfect fit?

Comment: It certainly *doesn't* represent a perfect fit. WIth a large enough sample even the noisiest and weakest of sample relationships can have extremely small p-values.

Comment: Please explain terms in the model incuding alpha, beta. What is log-return of index ?